# Globalization of windows application in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, vba

I have a **richtextbox** and **combobox** in my form. the richtext box contain some data and combobox has following items like

```
english
hindi
gujrati
marathi
urdu
```

So I want whenever user select any of these language then whole data of Richtextbox convert into that language which is user selected. I tried in google api but I want to do that without an internet connection.

Because all users don't have an internet connection due to some reasons. Please help me out.

Comment: What's in the rich text box?  Any old random text?

Comment: I'm not sure what the goal is: translating or globalizing? Globalization is completely different from translating user input.

Answer (score 1):

Its ok to support multiple languages in your applications by changing the label text etc to the language required by the user and its easy too.. Because you know which words have to be translated.But dont think you can easily translate any random user input to any language all by yourself and that too offline.Programs like Google translate uses complex algorithms (rather than simple text replcement) and relies on websites written in other languages to chose the best match.

Answer (score 0):

If the text in the Richtextbox is dynammic and either inserted by the user or modified by the user then you could try [FreeTranslator](http://www.softpedia.com/get/Others/Home-Education/FreeTranslator-Full-Version.shtml) or [Lingoes](http://www.lingoes.net/en/index.html), although I don't think either have an API that you can integrate with your application and I'm not positive if they support the languages you are looking for.

If the text is static, there are many resources available on how to do this, [Hanselman](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/GlobalizationInternationalizationAndLocalizationInASPNETMVC3JavaScriptAndJQueryPart1.aspx) has a good initial post and there are probably many links on the page that can lead you to further information.